# iOS16 NSURLSession support HTTP3 & QUIC protocol acquiescently?

Tags: ios16, quic, http3

Anybody notices NSURLSession HTTP3 is available on iOS16 without Cornet.framework, precondition, the HTTP server supports QUIC protocol?

Recently, debugging the NSURLSession function with server, captured package via WireShark, i can capture the QUIC package.

Is there any document or video come out of Apple to explain the Support HTTP3 acquiescently on iOS16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using URLSession, you don't need to change your app since iOS 15 and macOS Monterey ship with HTTP/3 enabled by default. Once you enable HTTP/3 on your server, you're good to go.

—— WWDC 2021 session Accelerate networking with HTTP/3 and QUIC：https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10094/?time=294